# Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#5) Unauthorized source IP

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, ip, facebook-opengraph, facebook-oauth

I have build facebook application but godaddy block IP address. Please resolve it as soon as possible.
https://rite5.com/fbapps/adv/
facebook app url https://apps.facebook.com/rite-five/
error :
Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#5) Unauthorized source IP address thrown in /home/content/68/9400868/html/fbapps/adv/base_facebook.php on line 1033

Comment: I am making API calls @davidrac

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm experiencing the same problems with my heroku app!

Comment: I have posted a step by step guide to resolve this issue, see https://apoorv.quora.com/OAuthException-Unauthorized-source-IP-address-Facebook-Application if it helps

Answer (score 1):

This means you're making API calls from an IP other than the one configured in your app settings in the `server whitelist` part of the app's advanced settings.
Update this value to reflect the actual IP addresses of your server(s)

Comment: @lgy yes dear you are right. I configured in advanced setting, now this error occurs 
Your IP should be included in the Update Settings IP Whitelist . You are currently connecting from 182.182.92.191. My hosting I.P address is  IP Address 118.139.174.1
Dedicated IP Address 118.139.174.13.

Comment: I don't know how your network is configured, only your system admin would be aware of that - the IPs to put into the field are the IPs that requests to Facebook from your software will be coming from

Comment: I put IP address from my godaddy hosting account. IP Address 118.139.174.1. but facebook says you are currently connecting from 182.182.92.191. I think this IP is my ISP's IP